# How to show a tooltip for rechart which is bigger than the chart

Tags: javascript, svg, frontend, tooltip, recharts

I'm using [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US) library to implement the [TinyLineChart](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/TinyLineChart) for my project.
It's all working fine until I tried to add custom tooltip for the chart.

I have drawn several charts and those heights are quite small.
[image: TinyCharts]

It looks fine at this stage, but when I'm implementing the tooltips for these charts, I found that it's clipping.
[image]

It feels like it is because the chart height is too small, but this is design and I cannot change it.
Ideally, I wonder if the tooltips can be drawn over the other charts. Like this.
[image]

I already tried to add css `{ overflow: hidden }` but failed.

I'm working on `recharts@2.3.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by passing z-index to `wrapperStyle` of `<Tooltip/>`. Like this:

```
wrapperStyle={{
        zIndex: 1,
}}
```

You might need to increase that number. I hope that helps!